# Does Tridion 2013 SP1 Content Delivery work under Java 8?

Tags: content-delivery

Is there anyone that has tried a full installation of the content delivery with XPM in Java 8? I know the prerequisites state that Java 7 is required, but I would like to know if anyone tried and manage to get it running under 8

Comment: Are you having problems getting it to work?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have not tried yet, I am checking if any people are using it in their production environment yet under Java 8, seeing as this would be reliable information to see if every function works, not just the core functionality/start up of the libraries.

Comment: If somebody had gone through the trouble to see if every function works, they'd likely be employed by SDL. In which case the platform would've been on the supported prerequisites. ;-)   I understand what you're looking for, but doubt anyone would've done any such thing beyond a dev environment (which usually precludes serious test coverage).

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried to install using Java 8 and is possible that the installation still works, but regardless if works or not, if you face any issues there is a big chance that your implementation is not going to be supported as didn't follow the prerequisites.

If there is a valid reason for install in Java 8 because specific technical requirements of the customer, my recommendation is to ask the question formally throughout SDL Customer Support and see which options your implementation has of still being supported.

If there is no valid reason for install in Java 8, my recommendation is to use the documented and supported prerequisites.

Comment: Of course, but my question is not directed to support, it is more out of curiosity. If I would use it and something would go wrong then it would be my own wrong doing and my own mess to clean up.